# ObjectId function invalid object id length error with $project using Mongodb 3.4.15

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

This is my aggregation

```
db.getCollection("entities").aggregate([
    {$match : {...omissis..},
    {$project : {ancestors : 1}},  
    {$unwind: "$ancestors"}]);
```

The result is

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b855ffb17285c29501dd801"), 
    "ancestors" : "5c62ef9b8521e37b80517583"
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b8537d3571c4f3e3c0dcf54"), 
    "ancestors" : "5c75565b3e44853a18cc9d11"
}
```

I want to convert the ancestors string into `ObjectId`.
I have done a lot of tests , my last one is adding this pipeline

```
{$project: {
             result : {
                    "$let" : {
                              "vars" : { "id" : "$ancestors" },
                              "in" : ObjectId('$$id')
                             }
                       }
           } 
 }
```

Every tests I made I have the same error

> Error: invalid object id: length :

The ancestors string is a valid `ObjectId` and I don't understand how to solve this error.

I know there are new commands with Mongodb 4.0 but this project still uses 3.4.15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `cursor` and `javascript` to achieve this. Please try this

```
db.getCollection("entities").aggregate([
    {$match : {...omissis..},
    {$project : {ancestors : 1}},  
    {$unwind: "$ancestors"}]).forEach(function(doc){
    doc.ancestors = ObjectId(doc.ancestors)
    print(doc);
    })
```

Comment: it works! Do you know if there is a way to continue with other pipelines ?

Comment: I tried lot of other options but this is the only one working

Comment: Yes, that’s the better choice